# How to automatically mount my Google Drive to Google Colab

Tags: google, colab

I have recently discovered Google Colab and I am wondering if there is an option to permanently authorize Google Colab to access and mount my Google Drive.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
Go to this URL in a browser: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=xxx
Enter your authorization code:
··········
Mounted at /content/drive
```

Right now, I need to all the time insert manually the authorization code and I want when I start a new Google Colab to have my drive mounted.

Is there an option to do that or I should execute this all the time manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Choose the folder icon in the left sidebar.
2. Wait for the runtime to initialize (you will see icons appear under the word "Files" in the sidebar).
3. Choose the Google Drive icon (the hover text is "Mount Drive").

Using this method, rather than messing up your notebook with the `google.colab` package, is nice and Colab maintains the authorization until you "Unmount Drive" using the crossed out Google Drive icon.

Comment: Your method is still a colab package. When you click on the "Google Drive icon", it just create two lines of code in the notebook "from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')". Every time the runtime is disconnected, we need to mount the drive again and give authentication

Comment: @HighGPA I've noticed that behavior too, but only on uploaded .ipynb files. If you create a new Colab document from drive, no lines are inserted with this method. I can't find any other difference between uploaded and new Colab documents (or a way to "convert" an uploaded file)!

Comment: You are definitely right. I am trying to find a solution too. It seems like that colab keep a hidden tag of the "original creator" somehow.

Answer (score 7):

For some reason, Colab allows me to automatically mount *if I'm the creator of the notebook*. If that's not the case, such was when I create a copy, the `from google.colab import drive` code block automatically gets added, and I have to authorize again.

```
File > New notebook
```

Then navigate to the file browser. Click on "Mount Drive".

From then on, every time I connect, it automatically mounts Drive during the `Initializing` phase.

Answer (score 2):

I was working on a google colab project, after a while I decided to copy the work and rename it as a new version (manual type of git control). After doing this I noticed that my google drive doesn't automatically mount. After checking some of the settings I went to **File > Update Drive Preview** after doing this, the google drive is automatically added when restarting the notebook. Even when commenting out these lines...

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Hope this helps

Comment: this doesn't work

Comment: Hi, this was way back in 2020, now there is a mount button in Colab!

Comment: The mount button only works for notebooks that you created. If you open an imported notebook (upload or drag and drop), you can't authorize permanently. You have to run the cell and authorize in the popup

Comment: Gianni, I have tested the methods myself - they work. The question is not how to authorize google colab access for note books that you don't own. That is a very different question and answer all together. Either way, the run in cell uses the method that I suggested.